# In Robocraft do I gain equal XP for doing damage in Single Player as I do in Team Death Match?

Tags: robocraft

I've been trying to grind levels in Robocraft and I've noticed that in Single Player I can gain XP versus the AI bots. Is this XP equal to XP earned for the same amount of damage done to players in PvP?